# Show that: $\int_\Gamma \frac{\log(z+i)}{1+z^2}dz\rightarrow 0 $ along the semicircle $\Gamma$ when we take $R\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

This is part of a bigger problem. My problem tells me I can use this fact. But I want to prove it.

> Show that: $$\int_\Gamma \frac{\log(z+i)}{1+z^2}dz\rightarrow 0 $$ along the semicircle $\Gamma$ when we take $R\rightarrow \infty$

Is there a **simple** way of calculating this? Please **do not** compute all calculations if it's a lot. I would simply like to know the steps e.g.

Parametrize, ML Lemma etc.

Comment: Is Gamma supposed to be an arbitrary semicircle? Which semicircle? I assume its radius is R? Where is it centered? What half of the plane does it correspond to?

Comment: Is the semicircle closed?

Comment: It's centered at $0$, goest from $\infty$ to $-\infty$, anticlockwise it's not closed. The next part of the question uses residue theorem to compute the closed semicircle. But I need to know that this path is $0$. The question doesn't specify if it's upper or lower. It's up to us to pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One has,  as $R \to \infty$,
$$
\left|\int_\Gamma \frac{\log(z+i)}{1+z^2}dz\right|=\left|\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\log(Re^{it}+i)}{1+R^2e^{2it}}Re^{it}dt\right|\leq\frac{\pi R\log(R^2+1)}{R^2-1}
$$
which tends to $0$.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed :)

Comment: You are welcome.